# 3 hour change at Stansted

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, airport-security

I have a flight Funchal->London Stansted. After 3 hours I have another flight Stansted->Bologna. Is this enough time to do passport control and security check? Handbag+checkin done

Do I need to do passport control and again security control for second flight?

Comment: Your previous question and its answer confirm you need to clear immigration on arrival, collect your bags and clear security for your onbound flight https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173546/i-have-2-flights-by-ryanair-funchal-stansted-and-stansted-bologna-do-i-need-to In theory 3 hours should normally be enough but several factors could jeopardise the transfer eg inbound flight is late, how busy the airport is on the date/time you’re travelling, what time the gate closes etc

Comment: If the answer to your previous question "Can I stay airside?" is correct (and it is: Stansted does not do transits) please 'accept' it. Also please see [Is a visa needed during a luggage-free transfer at Stansted (London, UK)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/160854/is-a-visa-needed-during-a-luggage-free-transfer-at-stansted-london-uk) You might need a visa.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to do passport control and again security control for second flight?

Yes.

> Is 3 hours enough?

No one knows. No connection is every guaranteed so best we can do is give you a likelihood. If all goes well 3 hours should be fine. Things that are most likely to go wrong:

1. Significant delay or schedule change for your first flight
2. Wait times at immigration. This depends a lot on your time of arrival and what else is happening. Recently very long wait times have been reported ([example](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-04-25/stansted-passengers-face-queues-of-nearly-two-hours-at-passport-control)). It's unclear whether these are outliers or regular occurrences at the moment.
3. Complication at immigration: if your paperwork (passport, visa, etc) are complicated or not fully in order, you may get a lot of question or they will need to double check some info.
4. Security to re-enter. Again, recently there have been reports of very long wait times ([example](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10804243/Furious-flyers-share-pictures-huge-passport-control-queues.html)). Again, it's unclear whether this happens a lot. To mitigate this one, you can buy [FastTrack](https://www.stanstedairport.com/at-the-airport/security-fasttrack/) access. I don't know whether this is actually faster, or just another marketing ploy.

Stansted recommends to be checked-in and head two security at least 2 hours before departure.

I'd say you have an about 90% chance of making it. However, if you miss it, you will likely lose your second ticket completely and may have to buy a new ticket on the spot and you are stuck in Stansted until the next available flight. Personally I don't do self connections under 4 hours, but that depends on your own risk tolerance.